# How to make Compact code Laravel 5 Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this not simple code on my **Controller**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\UserDetail;
use App\UserSex;
use App\Province;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller {

...

public function show($id) {
        //
        $User = User::find($id);
        $UserDetail = User::find($id)->UserDetail;
        $UserSex = User::find($id)->UserSex;
        $Province = User::find($id)->Province;
        return view('users.show', compact('UserDetail', 'User', 'UserSex', 'Province'));
    }

...
```

This code on one of my **Model**:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

...

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function UserDetail() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail', 'userDetail_id');
    }

    public function UserSex() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserSex', 'sex_id');
    }

    public function Province() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Province', 'province_id');
    }

...
```

And this code on **view**:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="isbn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="{!! $User->username !!}" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="{!! $UserDetail->firstName !!} {!! $UserDetail->lastName !!}" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="publisher" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sex</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sex" placeholder="{!! $UserSex->gender !!}" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you see in my **controller**, I call every function in model (**return view('users.show', compact('UserDetail', 'User', 'UserSex', 'Province'));**) to show the data between table in *Eloquent Relationships*.

I have no error doing code like this and this run well.

***My question is, am I doing it right (base on Laravel 5)?***

Because I think this method is **not simple**, **not compact** if I make a lot of table later. I still have not explored all the laravel features. Maybe some of you can help me make it right.

Comment: I think I made a mistake on my controller **Show** Function about ($id) parameter.
Now it's make me more confused.

Comment: what is the reason that you put UserSex and province into separate models?

Comment: @yangqi There is no reason to make them separate, I just following official Laravel 5.1 documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships. Am I wrong?

Comment: well, in my opinion, user detail and sex information are the properties of a user, so they should be handled in the User model, rather than having a separate model. Unless there are particular reasons to do so.

Comment: @yangqi you mean I must put all of my user data in one table?

Comment: yes, unless you have your specific reason to store them into different tables. UserSex and UserDetail all belong to User model, the way you are using would work, but I don't see any reason to make it such complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your method & variable names should be camel case see http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#4-2-properties & http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#4-3-methods

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\UserDetail;
use App\UserSex;
use App\Province;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller {

...

public function show($id) {
        //
        $user = User::find($id);
        $userDetail = User::find($id)->userDetail;
        $userSex = User::find($id)->userSex;
        $province = User::find($id)->province;
        return view('users.show', get_defined_vars());
    }
```

> Also you can use [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php). This will get all your defined
>   variables into the scope & will pass it to view.

Also change your method names to camel case

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

...

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function userDetail() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail', 'userDetail_id');
    }

    public function userSex() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserSex', 'sex_id');
    }

    public function province() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Province', 'province_id');
    }
```

Change your variables in the view

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="isbn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="{!! $user->username !!}" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="{!! $userDetail->firstName !!} {!! $userDetail->lastName !!}" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="publisher" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sex</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sex" placeholder="{!! $userSex->gender !!}" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Follow [PSR-2 — Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

> Also try use eager loading as it solves query n+1 problem
>   http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading &
>   limit your select

I would rather write this code in your controller for **`$user`** variable

```
$user = User::with(['userDetail' => function($q){
    $q->select(['id', 'firstName', 'lastName']);
}, 'userSex' => function($q){
    $q->select(['id', 'gender']);
}])->findOrFail($id);
```

and in your view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="isbn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="{!! $user->username !!}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="{!! $user->userDetail->firstName !!} {!! $user->userDetail->lastName !!}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="publisher" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sex</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sex" placeholder="{!! $user->userSex->gender !!}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Always limit your select & unnecessary joins as this can be expensive**

Comment: Hei **@ARIF MAHMUD RANA**, your controller script is great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Eager Loading** to boot up the models together, so that your controller will look like this:

```
$user=User::find($id)->with('UserDetail')->with('UserSex')->with('Province');

return view('users.show')->with('user',$user);
```

It will drastically increase the performance of your application.

For reference [Eloqouent - Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: Your code give me this error **"ErrorException in ca765b7a3065caff5ad7ab75ad6380bb line 15:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$username (View: C:\wamp\www\bookstore\resources\views\users\show.blade.php)"**

I think my table column is not defined using that (**$username** is on my view **"{!! $user->username !!}"**)